# data binding with dynamic set content view

Tags: android, android-databinding, android-mvvm

I am having a navigation drawer which needs to be used across two screens(First, Second). For this, I have created BaseActivity class which will have the navigation drawer implementation and one method to set the activity content dynamically as below.

```
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    protected View mainView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    protected void updateLayout(int layoutId){
        FrameLayout contentFrameLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.content_frame); //Remember this is the FrameLayout area within your activity_main.xml
        mainView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(layoutId, contentFrameLayout);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_first) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, FirstActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_second) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

updateLayout() method will update the activity content dynamically.

With this, I want to set data binding for the first screen which I am not able to do. Here is my code

```
public class FirstActivity extends BaseActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        updateLayout(R.layout.content_first);

        EmployBean bean = new EmployBean("100", "Rajesh");
        ContentFirstBinding mBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.content_first);
        EmployViewModel employViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(EmployViewModel.class);
        employViewModel.getEmployBean().setValue(bean);
        mBinding.setEmployViewModel(employViewModel);

    }
}
```

This is displaying the content_first as the main content without navigation drawer.

Can anyone help me how to solve this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid of

```
updateLayout(R.layout.content_first);
```

and change

```
ContentFirstBinding mBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.content_first);
```

with

```
ContentFirstBinding mBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(getLayoutInflater(), R.layout.content_first, (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.content_frame), true)
```

the last line will take care of inflate the layout for you, and add its content to  `(FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.content_frame)`

Answer (score 0):

You are Inflating the layout using DataBindingUtil but not setting it in the FrameLayout,

don't use

```
updateLayout(R.layout.content_first);
```

Instead of that, do this -

```
ContentFirstBinding mBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this,R.layout.content_first);
navigationView.addView(mBinding.getRoot())
```

Comment: This will set the content_first layout to the activity and no navigation drawer is displayed. But I want common navigation drawer to be shown in all activities

Comment: I thought the FrameLayout in inside your NavigationView in xml, you haven't provided the xml..then you have to do this : navigationView.addView(mBinding.getRoot()), as NavigationView itself derived from FrameLayout I think it will work..